# How can I use Java in Google Colab

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp, google-colaboratory

I want to use Stanford CoreNLP in my Google Colab Notebook. For that I need Java. Is there a way to install Java on those machines?

What I currently have is:

```
!pip install StanfordCoreNLP
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('stanford-corenlp', lang='de', memory='4g')
...
nlp.close()
```

and I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java': 'java'
```

Comment: Have you tried to `!apt install` the required packages? The ! at the start of the command simply runs it in a shell, you can make changes to the VM system with programs such as apt and pip..

Comment: Thank you!
**!apt install openjdk-9-jre** does work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this

```
import os       #importing os to set environment variable
def install_java():
  !apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null      #install openjdk
  os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"     #set environment variable
  !java -version       #check java version
install_java()
```

Comment: An update that may help someone: I had to put `!apt update` as the first line in the function install_java(), for the installation to work

Comment: correct, @Sanjeev, can you edit answer?